# Splitting individial elements from a textfile into arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I am trying to split the elements read from the textfile and write them into separate arrays in java.
INPUT is something like this :

> ID,ParentID,Name
>
> 4,17,abc
>
> 1,0,def
>
> 17,0,ghi
>
> 9,17,klm
>
> the OUTPUT should be :
>
> ghi,17
>
> klm,9
>
> abc,4
>
> def,1

It has to be sorted based on the id in the descending order. I think the most efficient way to do it is quicksort(I have an idea to do this). My question is I have split all elements of the text file but i am not able to create seperate arrays for id,parentid and name. After they are split into arrays and the ids are sorted,id should give their corresponding name.Can someone please help me out with writing into the array part? 
Thank you in advance.

I have gone so far :

```
import java.io.*;

public class Folder {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;         
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            String[] a=strLine.split(",",3);
            String id=a[0];
            String parentid=a[1];
            String name=a[2];
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
            //System.out.println (strLine);
        }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
        //Catch exception if any
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This will split all the elements from the text file.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try a few things. Looking at your example I would be temped to use a `Map` and use the id as the key, and have a list of other inputs e.g `Map<Integer,List<String>>` this is probably overkill for your example.

You could also make a new `Object` maybe

```
public Input implements Comparable<Input>{
    private int id;
    private int parentId;
    private String name;

    public Input(int a, int b, String c){
        //set params}
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Input o){
        Input input = (Input) o;
        return this.id - input.getId();
    }
}
```

You could then make an array if you know how many lines you have to read but use a collection if you dont as it will grow dynamically.

```
List<Input> inputList = new ArrayList<Input>();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
     String[] a=strLine.split(",",3);
     inputList.add(new Input(a[0],a[1],a[2]));
     ....
}
```

You then need to sort by Id and output.

Now that the `Input` implements `Comparable` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) we can sort it using `Collections.sort(inputList)` ([the javadoc explains how it deals with duplicates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)) it is then simply a case of iterating the list and outputting.

Comment: if i want to use a map,all the ids should be unique. what if there are duplicate ids? i want to sort the ids in the descending order and i want even the duplicate ids to appear after I sort.

Comment: I have expanded my answer using comparable as suggested in the other answer, No a map cannot contain duplicate keys so if they exist that is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the hard way.

Here's some advice:

- Don't build your data structures from primitive types and arrays.  Java has collection types (e.g. lists, maps, etcetera) and it allows you to create custom types.
- When you have a 2-D data structure and your primary requirement is to sort the rows, then don't make the columns the primary structure; i.e. if you have an array/list of rows it will be easier to sort by rows than an array of columns.
- There are standard (efficient) implementations of sorting in the Java libraries.  To make a custom class (or an array) sortable, you either need to declare the class as implementing `Comparable<TheClass>` or create a separator `Comparator<TheClass>` object.
- Use the javadoc to help you understand what is available in the standard libraries.

Comment: I am new to java. So how do I go about solving this problem? I need to sort the ids in descending order and print the appropriate name for those ids. If i use a map for the ids, then what will happen to the duplicate ids? what should i do if i want the duplicate ids to appear?